# Who is the parent of the executable program?

Tags: linux

I am not getting a valid answer about this that who is the parent of the executable program that is being created in linux(ubuntu).I got many answers like getppid(),ps commmands etc but not exactly the correct answer.i don't need ids and parent ids,its just simple who is the parent of any executable program?Is it the init or something else?
Help me please.

Comment: when you say "who" do you mean user that executes the parent program, or the executable name of the parent program?

Comment: It's whichever program that launched the thing. If you start it from your terminal, the parent will be the shell process(likely a running bash program) running in that terminal. A program might contain code to "detach" itself from the program that launched it though, in which case the init process will become its parent.

Comment: Basically the direct and indirect mother of all processes is init, which is process/pid 1. If you run 'ps -ef ' and follow most processes up the tree you'll find init at the top of the hierarchy. I said "Indirect" because many daemons wrap up to themselves, but under it all they were all kicked off under init, whether that was through a user issuing a command on a tty, or a process that spawned a process that spawned a process.

Comment: Also, I believe Ubuntu is using systemd now, but in ps it will still be called `init`.

Comment: @chugadie: i mean executable name of the parent program.

Comment: @JNevill: okay now i get it that it is the init, parent of all processes.Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access this information from the /proc file system on a Gnu/Linux install.

```
cat /proc/5741/stat | cut -d " " -f 4
5740
```

where 5741 is the process ID in question and 'stat' is a file that contains stauts information about the process.  The 4th field is the parent process ID.  For more information *man proc*

To get the name of the parent process, use the information from the first command and get the second field from stat

```
 cat /proc/5740/stat | cut -d " " -f 2
 (nginx)
```

All together

```
cat /proc/`cat /proc/5741/stat | cut -d " " -f 4`/stat | cut -d " " -f 2
```

My processes look like this from *ps -fax*

```
 5740 ?        S      0:00      |   \_ nginx: master process nginx
 5741 ?        S      0:00      |       \_ nginx: worker process
 5742 ?        S      0:00      |       \_ nginx: worker process
 5743 ?        S      0:00      |       \_ nginx: worker process
 5744 ?        S      0:00      |       \_ nginx: worker process
```